# Office 365 subscription notification

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

A user is continuously getting this notification in Office:

> ACCOUNT NOTICE. We've run into a problem with your Office 365 subscription and need your help to fix it

The user is licensed and has logged in to Office. I believe the installation is linked to a previous user who has since left and whose license has been removed.
I have tried the steps described [here](https://jaapwesselius.com/2014/11/12/weve-run-into-a-problem-with-your-office-365-subscription/). This has not worked. Is there a way to determine which account this was previously linked to?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling office using the account of the licensed user? Maybe some stuff in the regkeys is preventing it.

Comment: Reinstall will be my last resort, which is looking to be my option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran a full online repair as administrator, then when logging back on as the user the Office installation was reflecting correctly in Office 365. No need to register as the previous steps I ran in the link in original post changed the license installed. User was signed in and message is no longer displaying.